# External CSS: How to implement a class from a external css?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use this class from my external css:

```
.row.rectanglebox {
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    height: 210px;
    border: solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I've tried adding the following (which I normally would use) but to no avail:

```
<div class="rectanglebox">
       <p> sample text </p>
<div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is the following image:

[image]

Comment: Simply put both classes in the element: <div class="row rectanglebox">

Comment: Maybe you're missing the `row` class?

Comment: @FaustoNA Tried that but I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @ffxdean — That's the only problem with the code you've shared. If that doesn't fix the problem then the problem isn't expressed in the code in your question.

Comment: @Goombah It worked! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that in your CSS file, with `.row.rectangle` you are saying that any element that contains the `.row` class, and then the `.rectanglebox` class, or any element with the row class that has a child element with the `.rectanglebox` class will have these styles applied to it.

You can either change your code to `class="row rectangleclass"` or just change your CSS to simply `.rectangleclass { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `.row` class in your div, do this:

HTML:

```
<div class="row rectanglebox">
    <p> sample text </p>
<div>
```

when you see this: `.row.rectanglebox` it means that the element have both classes, but your div have only `.rectanglebox` class.

regards!

Answer (score 0):

It works here

```css
.row.rectanglebox {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 210px;
  border: solid black;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row rectanglebox">
  <p> sample text </p>
  <div>
```